# Error loading page while transiting from one page to another in jquery mobile+ Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on the Android hybrid application using **phonegap** and **JQuery Mobile**. My application involves user registration, sign in and payment. The problem I am facing is that when I try to navigate from one page to another I get message `error loading page`.

I am creating data-role pages and using `changepage` method to navigate to different page.

Here are the data-role pages and `js` file where I am getting this error.

First js File `bookingSearchResult.js`:

```
var jsonData=new Array();

$(document).ready(function(e) {


$(".radioCheck").live("change",(function(event, ui){

        var value=$(this).val();
        value=value.split("_");
        var str=value[0]+ "(INR"+value[1]+"/-)";
        var tempid=this.id;
        tempid=tempid.split("_");           
        $("#spRoomType_"+tempid[2]).html(str);
    }));




    $("#bookingform").live("pagebeforeshow",function(e){

        loadpagedata();


    }); 

    $("#btnFormSubmit").live("click",function(){

        $.blockUI({  message: '<div class="loading-text">Please wait...</div>' });
        var roomsData=$('#selectmenu2').val();
        var aduldetails=$('#selectmenu3').val();
        for(var i=1;i<=roomsData;i++){

        for(var j=1;j<=aduldetails;j++){
            var fname=$('#Fname_'+i+'_'+j+'').val();

            var lname=$('#Lname_'+i+'_'+j+'').val();

            var email=$('#Email_'+i+'_'+j+'').val();
            var mobile=$('#Monumber_'+i+'_'+j+'').val();


             if(fname=="")
              { 
                 $.unblockUI();  
                 jAlert('Please enter First Name','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valFname").focus();
                     });     
                 return false;
              }
              else if(!fname.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) 
              {
                  $.unblockUI();
                  jAlert('First Name can have alphabets only','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valFname").focus();
                 });     
                 return false;
              }
              else if(fname.length>15) 
              {
                     $.unblockUI();  
                     jAlert('First Name cannot be greater than 15 alphabets','Alert',function(){
                         $(".valFname").focus();
                     });         
                     return false;
              } 
             if(lname=="")
              { 
                  $.unblockUI();
                  jAlert('Please enter Last Name','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valLname").focus();
                 }); 
                 return false;
              }
              else if(!lname.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) 
              {
                  $.unblockUI();
                 jAlert('Last Name can have alphabets only','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valLname").focus();
                 });
                 return false;
              } 
              else if(lname.length>15) 
              {
                  $.unblockUI();
                 jAlert('Last Name cannot be greater than 15 alphabets','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valLname").focus();
                 });     
                 return false;
              }
             if(email=="")
             { 
                 $.unblockUI();
                 jAlert('Please enter Email Address','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valEmail").focus();
                 }); 
                 return false;
             }
             else if(!email.match(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[(2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|1?\d{1,2})(\.(2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|1?\d{1,2})){3} \])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)) 
             {
                 $.unblockUI();
                 jAlert('Enter valid Email Address','Alert',function(){
                     $(".valEmail").focus();
                 }); 
                 return false;
             } 
             if(mobile=="")
             { 
                 $.unblockUI();
                 jAlert('Please enter Mobile Number','Alert',function(){
                     $('.valMobile').focus();
                 });     
                 return false;
             }
             else if(!mobile.match(/([0-9]{10})$/)) 
             {
                 $.unblockUI();
                 jAlert('Enter valid 10-digit Mobile Number','Alert',function(){
                     $('.Monumber').focus();
                 });     
                 return false;
             }
        }           
     }
        $.unblockUI();  
       $.mobile.changePage("#bookingConf");     
    });
});


$('#bookingSearchResult').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event){

    $('#hotelListDiv').empty();
    $('#hotelList').empty();
    $('#detailsDiv').empty();

    $('#hDisplay').text("Hotels Available in "+$('#Cityname option:selected').text());

    var dayWise='';
    var priceBreakup='';
    var  dataRetrieved=new Array();
    var dynHotels="";
    dataRetrieved=JSON.parse(localStorage['search']);

    $.each(dataRetrieved, function (index, status) { 
        var cinDate=JSON.parse(localStorage['search'])[index].checkInDate;
        var checkinDate=displayDate2(cinDate);
        $('#topDate').text(checkinDate[0]);
        var nights=$('#nights').val();
        var rooms=new Array();
        var pax=new Array();
        var roomDetails='';
        var numAdults=new Array();
        numAdults[0]=$('#selectmenu3').val();

        if($('#selectmenu2').val()>1){
            for(var i=1;i<$('#selectmenu2').val();i++){

                numAdults[i]=$("#"+"selectmenu3"+i).val();
            }
        }
        for(var i=0;i<$('#selectmenu2').val();i++)
        {
            roomDetails="<br>"+roomDetails+"Room "+(i+1)+": "+numAdults[i]+" Adult</br>";
        }


        $.each(this.availabilityList, function (index, status) {

            var dynRates='';
            var hotel=this.hotelName;
            var hotelId=this.hotelId;
            var priceString="";

            $.each(this.rate, function (index, status) { 
                var offerPrice=this.price;
                var rateId=this.rateId;
                var rateDesc=this.rateIdTypeDesc;
                var roomVisited=0;
                var daySplit='';
                var dayWisePrice='';

                $.each(this.roomGrid.room, function (index, status) { 

                    if(roomVisited !=this.roomNumber ){
                        var roomNo=this.roomNumber;
                        var roomType=this.roomType;
                        var numOfPax=this.numOfPax;
                        $.each(this.daywiseRates, function (index, status) { 
                            var dateVisited=0;
                            $.each(this.forday, function (index, status) { 
                                if(dateVisited !=this.date ){
                                    var day=this.date;
                                    var dayWiseTotal=this.price;
                                    dayWisePrice=dayWisePrice+roomNo+"%"+numOfPax+"_"+day+":"+dayWiseTotal+"#";
                                    dateVisited=this.date;
                                }
                            });       
                        });
                    }
                    roomVisited=this.roomNumber;
                });
                var buttonId="btnBooknow_"+hotelId+"_"+rateId;
                var priceBreakupId="priceBreakupText$"+hotelId+"$"+rateId+"$"+dayWisePrice;

                dynRates=dynRates+'<li class="pricebreakup"><div class="pricebreakup-strip">'+rateDesc+' &#x20B9; '+offerPrice+'/-<br><span>(Lux. Tax Excl.)</span></div> <span class="priceBreak" id='+priceBreakupId+'>Price Breakup</span> <div class="submit-btn-wrap"><input name="Booknow" type="button" class="button-bg" id='+buttonId+' value="BOOK NOW"/></div></li>';
            });//end of rate
            dynHotels=dynHotels+'<div class="booking_search_result_hotel_item_wrap"><a id="info_popup" href="#info_popup" data-rel="dialog"  class="info_btn"><img src="images/i_ico.png" width="18" height="18" alt="Info"></a><div data-role="collapsible" id="hotelList" data-collapsed="true"><h3 id="hName">'+hotel+'</h3><ul class="form-list-item booking_search_result"><li class="booking_terms">Service tax @ 7.42% will be charged (As per new notification).</li><li class="check-in-details"><a id="policy_popup" href="#policy_popup" data-rel="dialog"  class="info_btn"><img src="images/p_ico.png" width="27" height="26" alt="i_ico" class="i_ico"></a> Check in:   '+checkinDate[1]+', '+nights+' Nights</span><br>'+roomDetails+'</li>'+dynRates+'</ul></div></div> ';
        });//end of availabilityList
    });
    $(dynHotels).appendTo('#hotelListDiv');

    $('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({refresh:true});
    $('input[type=button]').button({refresh:true});

    $('input[name="Booknow"]').click(function(){

        var btnId=this.id.split('_');
        hotelIdSelected=btnId[1];   
        rateIdSelected=btnId[2];
        $.mobile.changePage('#bookingform');
    });

    $('.priceBreak').click(function(){
        var id=this.id;
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
        {
            localStorage.priceBreakId=id;
        }
        $.mobile.changePage('#priceBreakup');
    });
});
```

Second `js` File : `bookingGuestDetails.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bookingConf").live("pagebeforeshow",function(e){

        loadBookingConfData();              
    }); 

    $(".edit-btn1").live("click",function(){

         var imgId=this.id;

            imgId=imgId.split('_');
         var str=imgId[1];

        $("#ulBookingConf li").empty();
        loadBookingConfDataForEdit();   
    });


    $("#btnSubmitConf").live("click",function(){
        $.blockUI({  message: '<div class="loading-text">Please wait...</div>' });
         var conFname=$(".clsConName").val();
         var conEmail=$(".clsConEmail").val();
         var conMobile=$(".clsConMobile").val();


         if(conFname=="")
          { 
             $.unblockUI();  
             jAlert('Please enter First Name','Alert',function(){
                 $(".clsConName").focus();
                 });     
             return false;
          }

          else if(!conFname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/))
          {
              $.unblockUI();
              jAlert('First Name can have alphabets only','Alert',function(){
                 $(".clsConName").focus();
             });     
             return false;
          }

          else if(conFname.length>15) 
          {
                 $.unblockUI();  
                 jAlert('First Name cannot be greater than 15 alphabets','Alert',function(){
                     $(".clsConName").focus();
                 });         
                 return false;
          } 


         if(conEmail=="")
         { 
             $.unblockUI();
             jAlert('Please enter Email Address','Alert',function(){
                 $(".clsConEmail").focus();
             }); 
             return false;
         }
         else if(!conEmail.match(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[(2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|1?\d{1,2})(\.(2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|1?\d{1,2})){3} \])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)) 
         {
             $.unblockUI();
             jAlert('Enter valid Email Address','Alert',function(){
                 $(".clsConEmail").focus();
             }); 
             return false;
         } 

         if(conMobile=="")
         { 
             $.unblockUI();
             jAlert('Please enter Mobile Number','Alert',function(){
                 $('.clsConMobile').focus();
             });     
             return false;
         }
         else if(!conMobile.match(/([0-9]{10})$/)) 
         {
             $.unblockUI();
             jAlert('Enter valid 10-digit Mobile Number','Alert',function(){
                 $('.clsConMobile').focus();
             });     
             return false;
         }
         $.unblockUI();
         createProvisional();
    });
});

function loadBookingConfData(){ 
    var noOfRoom=$('#selectmenu2').val();
    var nights=$('#nights').val();  
    var noOfAdults=0;
    var cinDate=JSON.parse(localStorage['search'])[0].checkInDate;
    var displayDate=displayDate2(cinDate)[1];
    var roomDetails='<li class="booking_full_guest_head"><ul id="booking_full_guest_head_ul"><li>Hotel <span id="hotelConf">'+localStorage.hotelNameGuestDetails+'</span></li><li>Check-in <span id="CheckinConf">'+displayDate+'</span></li><li>Nights <span id="NightsConf">'+nights+'</span></li></ul></li>';

    for(var i=1;i<=noOfRoom;i++)
    { 
        roomDetails+='<li><div class="booking_full_guest_head_edit">Room-'+i+'<br>'+$("#spRoomType_"+i).html()+'<a href="#" class="edit-btn"><img class="edit-btn1" id="imgEdit_'+i+'" src="images/edit-ico.jpg" width="19" height="18" alt="Edit"></a></div></li> ';

        if(i!=1){
            noOfAdults=$('#selectmenu3'+(i-1)).val();

        }
        else
        {

            noOfAdults=$('#selectmenu3').val();
        }
        for(var j=1;j<=noOfAdults;j++){

            if(document.getElementById('Gender_'+i+'_'+j+'_0').checked)
            {   
                roomDetails+='<li class="bookinsg_full_guest_adult_seprator"><div class="booking_full_guest_type_head"> Adult '+j+'</div><div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="textinput">Name </label> <input class="enFields_'+ i +'" disabled="disabled" name="textinput" type="text" id="Fname1_'+i+'_'+j+'" value="'+$("#Fname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+' '+$("#Lname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div><div data-role="fieldcontain" class="radio-input-wrap"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><label class="gender-label">Gender<span class="mandatory-gender-sign">*</span></label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" disabled="disabled" name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'" type="radio" id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0" value="" checked /><label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0">Male</label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'" id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1" value="" /> <label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1">Female</label></fieldset></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Email </label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" name="textinput" disabled="disabled" type="email" id="Email1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  value="'+$("#Email_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div> <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Number </label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" name="textinput" type="number" id="Monumber1_'+i+'_'+j+'" disabled="disabled" value="'+$("#Monumber_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /> </div></li>';
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Gender_'+i+'_'+j+'_1').checked)
            {   
                roomDetails+='<li class="bookinsg_full_guest_adult_seprator"><div class="booking_full_guest_type_head"> Adult '+j+'</div><div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="textinput">Name </label> <input class="enFields_'+ i +'" disabled="disabled" name="textinput" type="text" id="Fname1_'+i+'_'+j+'" value="'+$("#Fname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+' '+$("#Lname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div><div data-role="fieldcontain" class="radio-input-wrap"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><label class="gender-label">Gender<span class="mandatory-gender-sign">*</span></label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" disabled="disabled" name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'" type="radio" id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0" value="" /><label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0">Male</label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'" id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1" value="" checked/> <label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1">Female</label></fieldset></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Email </label><input  class="enFields_'+ i +'" name="textinput" type="email" id="Email1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  value="'+$("#Email_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" disabled="disabled"/></div> <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Number </label><input class="enFields_'+ i +'" name="textinput" type="number" id="Monumber1_'+i+'_'+j+'" disabled="disabled" value="'+$("#Monumber_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /> </div></li>';
            }                   
        }

    }
    var netCost="";
    netCost=calcTotalResevationCost();
    roomDetails+='<li class="booking_full_guest_adult_seprator booking_full_guest_adult_total">Total Cost &nbsp; INR '+ netCost +' /-</li><li class="submit-btn-wrap"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-bg" id="btnCreateProv"  value="Save"/><br><input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" class="button-bg"/></li>';
    $("#ulBookingConf").empty();

    $(roomDetails).appendTo("#ulBookingConf").trigger("create");
}


function loadBookingConfDataForEdit(){
    var cinDate=JSON.parse(localStorage['search'])[0].checkInDate;
    var displayDate=displayDate2(cinDate)[1];
    var nights=$('#nights').val();  
    var noOfRoom=$('#selectmenu2').val();
    var noOfAdults=0;
    var roomDetails='<li class="booking_full_guest_head"><ul id="booking_full_guest_head_ul"><li>Hotel <span id="hotelConf">'+localStorage.hotelNameGuestDetails+'</span></li><li>Check-in <span id="CheckinConf">'+displayDate+'</span></li><li>Nights <span id="NightsConf">'+nights+'</span></li></ul></li>';

    for(var i=1;i<=noOfRoom;i++)
    { 
        roomDetails+='<li id="liConfPage"><div class="booking_full_guest_head_edit">Room-'+i+'<br>'+$("#spRoomType_"+i).html()+'<a href="#" class="edit-btn"><img class="edit-btn1" id="imgEdit_'+i+'" src="images/edit-ico.jpg" width="19" height="18" alt="Edit"></a></div></li> ';

        if(i!=1){
        noOfAdults=$('#selectmenu3'+(i-1)).val();   
        }
        else
        {       
            noOfAdults=$('#selectmenu3').val();
        }
        for(var j=1;j<=noOfAdults;j++){
            if(document.getElementById('Gender_'+i+'_'+j+'_0').checked)
            {   
                roomDetails+='<li id="liConfPageGender" class="bookinsg_full_guest_adult_seprator"><div class="booking_full_guest_type_head"> Adult '+j+'</div><div data-role="fieldcontain" id="guestDetails"> <label for="textinput">Name </label> <input class="clsConName"  name="textinput" type="text" id="Fname1_'+i+'_'+j+'" value="'+$("#Fname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+' '+$("#Lname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div><div data-role="fieldcontain" class="radio-input-wrap"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><label class="gender-label">Gender<span class="mandatory-gender-sign">*</span></label><input type="radio" class="clsConRadio"  name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0" value="" checked /><label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0">Male</label><input type="radio" class="enFields_'+ i +'" name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'" id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1" value="" /> <label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1">Female</label></fieldset></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Email </label><input class="clsConEmail" name="textinput" type="text" id="Email1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  value="'+$("#Email_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div> <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Number </label><input type="text" class="clsConMobile" name="textinput"  id="Monumber1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  value="'+$("#Monumber_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /> </div></li>';
            }
            else if(document.getElementById('Gender_'+i+'_'+j+'_1').checked)
            {   
                roomDetails+='<li class="bookinsg_full_guest_adult_seprator" id="liConfpagefulldetails"><div class="booking_full_guest_type_head"> Adult '+j+'</div><div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="textinput">Name </label> <input type="text" class="clsConName"  name="textinput"  id="Fname1_'+i+'_'+j+'" value="'+$("#Fname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+' '+$("#Lname_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div><div data-role="fieldcontain" class="radio-input-wrap"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><label class="gender-label">Gender<span class="mandatory-gender-sign">*</span></label><input type="radio" class="enFields_'+ i +'"  name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0" value="" /><label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_0">Male</label><input type="radio" class="enFields_'+ i +'"  name="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'" id="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1" value="" checked/> <label for="Gender1_'+i+'_'+j+'_1">Female</label></fieldset></div><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Email </label><input  type="text" class="clsConEmail" name="textinput"  id="Email1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  value="'+$("#Email_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /></div> <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="textinput">Number </label><input type="text" class="clsConMobile" name="textinput"  id="Monumber1_'+i+'_'+j+'"  value="'+$("#Monumber_"+i+"_"+j).val()+'" /> </div></li>';
            }                   
        }
    }
     var netCost="";
     netCost=calcTotalResevationCost();
     roomDetails+='<li class="booking_full_guest_adult_seprator booking_full_guest_adult_total">Total Cost &nbsp; INR '+ netCost +' /- </li><li class="submit-btn-wrap"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-bg" id="btnSubmitConf"  value="Save"/><br><input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" class="button-bg"/></li>';
    $("#ulBookingConf").empty();

    $(roomDetails).appendTo("#ulBookingConf").trigger("create");


}
```

Follows is our data-role pages for booking, one is `bookingform` and other is `bookingConfirmationPage`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title>Ginger</title>



<link href="css/dark-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!--<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> --> 
<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jalerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
<!-- Includes Mobiscroll -->
<link href="css/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body class="booking-bg" id="gingerAppBody">
<div data-role="page" id="booking" data-theme="a" class="form-content-wrap home-bg">

<div data-role="header" data-id="ginger_header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>BOOKING</h1> 



<!------------- booking form page --------------------->
<div data-role="page" id="bookingform" data-theme="a" class="form-content-wrap">

<div data-role="header" data-id="ginger_header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>BOOKING</h1> 
    <a href="#bookingSearchResult" data-role="button" data-icon="gback" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop">Back</a>

    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="call" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" id="call-btn">Call</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="menu" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Menu</a>
  </div>
<form method="get">
<div data-role="content" class="form-content-wrap" > 
      <div data-role="collapsible-set" class="booking_form_wrap" id="roomListDiv"></div>

      <ul  class="form-list-item">
        <li class="booked-by-head">
            Booked By...
        </li>
        <li>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <select name="flipswitch3" id="flipswitch3" data-role="slider">
              <option value="off">Off</option>
              <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
            <label for="flipswitch3">Booker is same as guest 1</label>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="text" name="Fname" id="BookerFname" value=""  placeholder="First Name" />            
          </div>
          <span class="mandatory-sign">*</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="text" name="Lname" id="BookerLname" value="" placeholder="Last Name"  />
          </div>
          <span class="mandatory-sign">*</span>
        </li>  
        <li class="radio-input-li">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="radio-input-wrap">
              <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

                <label class="gender-label">Gender 
                <span class="mandatory-gender-sign">*</span></label>
                <input name="BookerGender" type="radio" id="BookerGender_0" value=""/>
                <label for="BookerGender_0">Male</label>             
                <input type="radio" name="BookerGender" id="BookerGender_1" value="" />
                <label for="BookerGender_1">Female</label>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
        </li>                 
        <li>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="BookerEmail" value="" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <span class="mandatory-sign">*</span>
        </li>  
        <li>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <input type="tel" name="Monumber" id="BookerMonumber" value="" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
          </div>
          <span class="mandatory-sign">*</span>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <select name="flipswitch2" id="flipswitch2" data-role="slider">
              <option value="off">Off</option>
              <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
            <label for="flipswitch2">Subscribe to the 'Ginger' newsletter</label>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="submit-btn-wrap">      
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnFormSubmit" class="button-bg"/>    
            <br>
            <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset" class="button-bg"/> 
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<!------------- booking confirmation page --------------------->


<div data-role="page" id="bookingConf" data-theme="a" class="form-content-wrap">

<div data-role="header" data-id="ginger_header">
    <h1>BOOKING</h1> 
    <a href="#bookingform" data-role="button" data-icon="gback" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="pop">Back</a>

    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="call" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" id="call-btn">Call</a>

    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="menu" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Menu</a>
  </div>
<form method="get">
<div data-role="content" class="form-content-wrap" > 
       <ul id="ulBookingConf" class="form-list-item booking_payment">



       </ul>
</div>
</form>
</div>




</div>


<script src="js/head.min.js"></script>

<script>
head.js("js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "cordova-2.1.0.js", "js/jquery-ui.min.js", "js/jquery.blockUI-min.js","js/jquery.alerts.min.js","jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js","js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.js","js/registration.js","js/booking.js","js/bookingSearch.js","js/bookingSearchResult.js","js/bookingGuestDetails.js","js/paymentSuccess.js","js/priceBreakup.js","js/common.js",function(){
    //head.js("js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "cordova-2.1.0.js", "js/jquery-ui.min.js", "js/jquery.blockUI-min.js","js/jquery.alerts.min.js","jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js","js/mobiscroll-2.3.1.custom.js","js/default.js","js/registration1.js","js/booking1.js","js/paymentSuccess.js",function(){
        localStorage.clear();
        $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
        $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true ;

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady(){

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){

            if($.mobile.activePage.is('#booking')){

                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else {

                navigator.app.backHistory();
            }
        }, false); 
        }
});

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery mobile this 
`$(document).ready(function(){`

is not needed (actually is wrong to use it like this. [See here.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html))
When you navigate to a page, a series of events is being fired. 
pagebeforecreate, pagecreate, pagebeforeshow, pageshow etc are some of 
them. You bind to those events not document ready. Since you use 
phonegap you should see the [deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready) event and [mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html).